# Lag and slowness problems with vim extension in vscode

Tags: performance, visual-studio-code

Recently I installed the vim extension in the visual study code, everything was going very well at first but after a couple of days the extension started working very slowly, I don't understand why this happens, I was reading and performance problems can occur because of the excessive amount of extensions in addition to having a bad computer, in my case neither of the two options apply, because I don't have more than 7 extensions and my pc is not so bad (processor and ram):
PROCESSOR: AMD Ryzen 5 3500U with Radeon Vega Mobile Gfx (8) @ 2.100GHz
RAM: 12G RAM DDR4 2600 Mhz

I don't know if there is a solution to this problem as some configuration for both the extension and the editor, otherwise I don't know if it can be that the extension is badly optimized.
I use the editor in windows 10 and arch linux, but in both operating systems I have the same problem

Comment: It seems that there are open issues about this that date back to 2017 that have not yet been resolved.